# Algorithms: Esau-Williams algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, network-programming

I would like to ask are there any sittuations that Esau-Williams algorithm may be useful? I know that it is used to solve CMST problem, but I can't find any sittuation that CMST problem may appear.

Comment: For the curious (not necessarily an answer) - [Revisiting Esau-Williams' Algorithm (CiteSeerX)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.346)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitated_minimum_spanning_tree), "CMST problem is important in network design: when many terminal computers have to be connected to the central hub, the star configuration is usually not the minimum cost design. Finding a CMST that organizes the terminals into subnetworks can lower the cost of implementing a network."

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, CMST stands for Capacitated Minimum Spanning Tree where each nodes have limited capacity to connect to other nodes. This makes a node to connect to limited number of other nodes depending on the node's capacity. 
Typically in any practical applications, a minimum spanning tree is not the only objective. There can be a lot of other constraints as well, for instance, in a network design the maximum amount of data that the output port of router(node) can handle is one capacity constraint. This marks the importance on heuristic algorithms like Esau-Williams CMST algorithm, Modified Kruskal CMST Algorithm etc..
Like networking any field which uses graphs, for example logistics, based on their constraints can use heuristic algorithms like Esau-William

Answer (score 0):

CMST can be utilised in cases such as deciding the cable layout for offshore wind turbines where each turbine has to be connected to a point in euclidean space called sub station. We cant use minimum spanning tree because it has capacity limitation on the number of turbines that can be connected on a single cable.